as if a penguin was or as if a penguin were
I've searched several questions about this, but can't find what I want to know. This is a problem in the English test in the country of Asia region. And our teacher has a doubtful reputation for his grammar knowledge. So I come to ask a question. Below are an original sentence and an altered sentence.
Original sentence

The penguin stared at me, and then at the pool, like he was asking, "Ah! Is this where the fish come from?"

Altered sentence

The penguin stared at me, and then at the pool, as if he was asking, "Ah! Is this where the fish come from?"

In the sentence, 'he' means 'a penguin'. Then, it becomes clear that this is a hypothetical situation. (The penguin can't say even a word, and no personification is being used in the whole story.) When 'like' is used, it can't express the subjunctive mood, so 'was' must be used. But the conjunction is replaced with 'as if', it is the subjunctive mood. Then how can 'was' be a grammatically accurate expression?

I think what you've been taught about the subjunctive doesn't match how it's actually used by native speakers. Questions about learning English normally go in ell.stackexchange.com, for future reference.

Maybe no personification is being used in the whole story, but it is here.

Like he was asking is an informal usage, so it would be incongruous to use the subjunctive were.
It would be strictly correct to use the subjunctive in as if he were, but in current English it is acceptable not to use it. See this question. So the sentence containing as if he was asking is a valid one.

That doesn’t mean it ᴡᴏɴ’ᴛ be marked wrong by someone looking to test this. What I mean by this is that if someone has taught their class a specific lesson that as if/though takes the irrealis were form rather than a preterite was/were agreeing in number with its subject, then it would be expected for them to pose a question about this on a quiz, test, or exam. In that scenario where they’re testing whether the students have learnt the lesson taught, the instructor might well mark wrong any other answer ʙᴜᴛ were there—ɴᴏᴛᴡɪᴛʜꜱᴛᴀɴᴅɪɴɢ the frequency of was in actual native speech.

Is this regional?  (My uninformed impression is that the subjunctive is used more commonly in the UK than the US — though, as you say, even in the UK it's far from universal, and comments to the linked question suggest it's the opposite way around!)

@tchrist True, but ELU deals with standard usage not examinerindulgese.

@EdwinAshworth This came from a test given in Asia. The scenario I suggested is therefore perfectly possible and perhaps even likely in order to understand the source of confusion. Remember that the goal is to pass the test, nothing more.

@tchrist ELU goals don't prioritise test-passing at the expense of decent usage / analysis.
